# Announcing the first full election for Arts & Crafts!

Tags: discussion, election

Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **7 March 2022**, as your first full election as a result of having [lost your beta label](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta) in December 2021.

The timeline:

- Today (28 Feb), I've posted a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can propose questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on 7 March 2022, users can [nominate themselves](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On 14 March, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to keep the total number of moderators on the site at 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on 22 March (or 29 March, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.